# Stuck on PHP to Python Translation

Tags: php, python, arrays

I'm attempting to translate some PHP code to Python and I'm stuck on the 4th line in the following code (included for context):

```
$table = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
    $char = substr($text, $i, $look_forward);
    if (!isset($table[$char])) $table[$char] = array();
}
```

If `array()` is used to create an array in PHP, what is `$table[$char] = array()` doing? Creating a new array inside an existing array? Or is it extending the array?

What is this accomplishing? What would be the Python equivalent to this?

`if (!isset($table[$char])) $table[$char] = array();`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, you should use another data structure than `list` as `table` variable. I suppose that `dict` should be nice for the purpose.

I've just made a quick try to mimic your PHP code in Python:

```
table = {} # use dictionary instead of list here
for char in text:
    if char not in table:
        table[char] = []
    # do your stuff with table[char]
    pass
```

Also, I suggest you look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

With the class the code could be rewritten in the following way:

```
import collections

table = collections.defaultdict(list)
for char in text:
    # do your stuff with table[char], empty list is created by default
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

**if (!isset($table[$char])) $table[$char] = array();**  is setting value of **$table[$char]** variable as **array()** if **$table[$char]** is not set yet

$table is empty array, so it has not contain "**$char**" as key so its checking if **$table[$char]** is set or not , if not then set its **($table[$char])** value as **array()**.

if you put your code like

```
$table = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
    $char = substr($text, $i, $look_forward);
    $table[$char] = array();
}
```

then it gives notice like Notice: **Undefined index: $char in**